# What is the difference between NBO program and NBO that we find in Gaussian?

Tags: computational-chemistry, gaussian, orbitals, population-analysis

I'm a little bit lost with NBO (natural bond orbital) analysis in Gaussian. I was told that `pop=NBO` in Gaussian gives me the charges of atoms, but that the NBO program can give the composition of a "localized orbitals".

Is it possible to perform this latter type of analysis in Gaussian or can we only extract NBO charges?

Comment: Gaussian actually is generally packaged with version 3 of the NBO program, as well as having an interface to more recent versions of NBO. Could you clarify what you mean/what you want in terms of getting the composition of an orbital?

Comment: In short, different program packages contain different versions of the NOB program (and corresponding interface), see examples: https://nbo6.chem.wisc.edu/affil_css.htm
@Tyberius I think you can/should expand your commnet to an answer.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if you can update us since it's been 6+ months? Were the comments by Greg and Tyberius useful? Did you figure out the answer? Is this still problem for you?

Comment: I think it's enough thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I asked](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9269/what-is-the-difference-between-nbo-program-and-nbo-that-we-find-in-gaussian#comment21583_9269) if the comment [by Tyberius](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9269/what-is-the-difference-between-nbo-program-and-nbo-that-we-find-in-gaussian#comment19391_9269):

> "Gaussian actually is generally packaged with version 3 of the NBO program, as well as having an interface to more recent versions of NBO. Could you clarify what you mean/what you want in terms of getting the composition of an orbital?"

and the comment [by Greg](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9269/what-is-the-difference-between-nbo-program-and-nbo-that-we-find-in-gaussian#comment19393_9269):

> "In short, different program packages contain different versions of the NOB program (and corresponding interface), see examples: nbo6.chem.wisc.edu/affil_css.htm @Tyberius I think you can/should expand your commnet to an answer."

were enough to answer their question, [and they replied with](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9269/what-is-the-difference-between-nbo-program-and-nbo-that-we-find-in-gaussian#comment21600_9269):

> "I think it's enough thank you."

So this question no longer needs to be in the unanswered queue, but it doesn't need to be closed either, since it got an "answer".